# How to show different databases MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

I downloaded [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/), and installed it correctly.

When I started the MySQL workbench it shows me these databases (I don't remember all of them):
**sakila

test

world**

It is ok, they are work, I can access them with no problems. But later I installed **xampp**, after that when start MySQL workbench it shows me different databases:
**cdcol

phpmyadmin

test

webauth**

I can't access the previous databases.

How to switch between them?, or
view them all?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether xampp uninstalled your first server, but it is more likely that its installation changed the default MySQL TCP/IP port (3306). Maybe both servers try to run on the same port (which doesn't work) and one failed to start (in this case the first installation).

So what you need is to make each server run on its own port. You can use MySQL Workbench to make the necessary change. However first you need to check if still both servers are installed. Do you have 2 MySQL services running? Switch off one of them and connect with MySQL to the running server. If that works shut this down and run the other service. Connect again with MySQL but this time go to the admin section, config file, and change the port to e.g. 3307. Save and restart the server (all within WB possible). Now you should be able to run both servers at the same time (provided the first one runs still on the default port). Create a second connection and server instance in WB so that you can access one server at 3306 and the other at 3307

If there's only one MySQL service entry then xamp has removed the previous installation and you must install it again if you really need two servers.